Как сделать что бы ссылка в select открывалась в новом окне
    <div class="hid-spis">
        <select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href = this.value" id="city-dropdown1">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Покупателям</option>
            <option value="https://www.gismeteo.ru">gismeteo</option>
            <option value="http://www.nova-wings.ru/forecast/">nova-wings</option>
        </select>
        
        </div>



JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?

Для этого можно использовать window.open(), где первым параметром нужно передавать URL, а вторым '_blank'.
Например:
<div class="hid-spis">
  <select
    onchange="if (this.value) window.open(this.value, '_blank');"
    id="city-dropdown1"
  >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Покупателям</option>
    <option value="https://www.gismeteo.ru">gismeteo</option>
    <option value="http://www.nova-wings.ru/forecast/">nova-wings</option>
  </select>
</div>

